# Billing cycles id generator or How to calculate number of period has passed since the first date

Tags: javascript, python, date, billing

Currently I generate this data and use it to get billing cycle ID: Cycle always start at day x of every month and x currently equal to 1

```
ID | StartDate | EndDate
1  | 2006/01/01| 2006/01/31
2  | 2006/02/01| 2006/02/28
3  | 2006/03/01| 2006/03/31
4  | 2006/04/01| 2006/04/30
5  | 2006/05/01| 2006/05/31
...
```

So if the date fall between start and end date its cycle id will be the ID. Is there a way to quickly calculate billing ID without look up to this table? In other world let say the very first cycle is 2006/01/01 -> 2006/01/31 and have the ID = 1, is there any formula to calculate 2006/05/07 fall into cycle 5?
I need something more generalize let say billing date is day X of every month. First billing is Y.\

Thank you

Comment: could you use the month? :D

Comment: @FrancescoLisandro Actually good idea  something like (current year - start year) * 12 + (current month - start month) ?

Comment: Yes it works. It's incremental ;)